# ffmpeg-python 'OSError[2] No such file or directory' error

Tags: python, docker, flask, ffmpeg

I recently wanted to integrate ffmpeg-python with my dockerized flask app. I installed ffmpeg through homebrew on my mac. It works when I do it manually but when it comes to my project. I cannot run ffmpeg. It throws `OSError[2]: No such file or directory` 
Here is my code in **views.py**:

```
@admin.route('/partners/upload_videos')
def partners_video_upload():

    # Uploading video using ffmpeg-python
    (ffmpeg
        .input('in.mp4')
        .output('output.mp4')
        .run()
        )


    return render_template('admin/partner/upload_videos.html')
```

the in.mp4 video file is in the same directory as **views.py*** file. I cannot seem to resolve the issue. I tried with `subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.run()` as well. Still the same error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. By the default when ffmpeg is installed in a docker container and `in.mp4` is specified, ffmpeg looks at the root directory of the project. So we have to specify the full path for ffmpeg to find your input video. So I did it that way and it worked nicely!
Here is my code:

```
@admin.route('/partners/upload_videos')
def partners_video_upload():

    # Uploading video using ffmpeg-python
    (ffmpeg
        .input('.\myproject\static\videos\in.mp4')
        .output('.\myproject\static\videos\converted\output.mp4')
        .run()
        )

    return render_template('admin/partner/upload_videos.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

A Docker image is an isolated, standalone filesystem. And it runs Linux. You can't access executables installed via Homebrew. So you need to install ffmepg *inside* the image, e.g. `RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg` in the `Dockerfile` if it's a Debian-based image.

Comment: I installed it to docker through Dockerfile as this `RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg` then it gave me this error `Error: ffmpeg error (see stderr output for detail)`

Comment: My code is:
`try:
        stream = ffmpeg.input('in.mp4')
        stream = ffmpeg.hflip(stream)
        stream = ffmpeg.output(stream, 'output.mp4')
        ffmpeg.run(stream, capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)

    except ffmpeg.Error as e:
        print('stdout:', e.stdout.decode('utf8'))
        print('stderr:', e.stderr.decode('utf8'))
        raise e
 `

Comment: I tried to print the error here what it gives me: 
`('stderr:', u"ffmpeg version 3.2.14-1~deb9u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers\n  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516\n  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls ...  54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100\n/in.mp4: No such file or directory\n")`